# crashes when using grid with ttk widgets

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, ttk

I need a specific layout for the gui I'm making with Tkinter/ttk on python 2.7, that's why I want to use the grid positioner to master my ttk widgets' relative positions. But everytime I run my code, nothing appears.

ps: I used some widgets with grid(), and some others with pack()

I don't know where's the problem! Here's the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
master = Tk()

f4=Frame(master,width=300,height=300,bg="powder blue",relief=SUNKEN)
f4.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=BOTH, expand=True)
test = True
f3=Frame(master,width=300,height=300,bg="red",relief=SUNKEN)
f3.pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH, expand=True)
def create():
    global test
    if test:
        global e
        e = ttk.Entry(f4).grid(row=2,column=0, columnspan=2)
    test = False

#e.focus_set()

def callback():
    print e.get()

b = Button(master, text="get", width=10, command=callback)
b.grid(row=0, column=0)
c = Button(master, text="set", width=10, command=callback)
c.grid(row=0, column=1)
create()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide some code related to your problem. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We cannot help you without seeing the code in question that is causing the issue. I can tell you if things are written correctly you should have no problem with `grid()`, `pack()` or `place()` in tkinter. Keep in mind you cannot use `grid()` and `pack()` within the same container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the use of `pack()` and `grid()` at the same time on the `master` window.

Use one or the other per container.

A container is the main `root` window, a `Toplevel()` window or a `Frame`.

Try something like this without `pack()`:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

master = Tk()
master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
master.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

f3=Frame(master,width=300,height=300,bg="red",relief=SUNKEN)
f3.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")

f4=Frame(master, width=300, height=300, bg="powder blue", relief=SUNKEN)
f4.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")

test = True

def create():
    global test
    if test:
        global e
        e = ttk.Entry(f4).grid(row=2,column=0, columnspan=2)
    test = False

def callback():
    print e.get()

b = Button(master, text="get", width=10, command=callback)
b.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="e")

c = Button(master, text="set", width=10, command=callback)
c.grid(row=2, column=1,  sticky="w")

create()
master.mainloop()
```

Here is a version just using `pack()`.

I changed it up a little to give a different layout that might be closer to what you are trying.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk


master = Tk()

f3 = Frame(master, width=300, height=300, bg="red", relief=SUNKEN)
f3.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

f4 = Frame(master, width=300, height=300, bg="powder blue", relief=SUNKEN)
f4.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

f5 = Frame(master, width=300)
f5.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH)

test = True

def create():
    global test
    if test:
        global e
        e = ttk.Entry(f4).pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH)
    test = False

def callback():
    print e.get()

b = Button(f5, text="get", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
c = Button(f5, text="set", width=10, command=callback)
c.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

create()
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you!! indeed the problem is the use of both grid() and pack() in the same container.